# Plesk Installation Configuration PSA Database

Tags: ubuntu, plesk, plesk-onyx

I am getting the following error on installation;
I am trying to install Plesk via the :8447 web port. Installation did fail on initial attempt. Server was rebooted and a following attempt was made.
**Have also removed the installer and downloaded again.** Same Error:

```
===> Performing safe prep-install database actions

Trying to start service mysql... /usr/sbin/mysqld (pid 1688) is running...
done
Trying to establish test connection... connected
done
===> Installing psa database
Trying to find psa database... DATABASE ERROR!!!
Database psa found, but version undefined

ERROR while trying to find
psa
database

Check the error reason (see log file: /var/log/plesk/install/plesk_18.0.31_installation.log), fix and try again
***** problem report *****
ERROR while trying to find
psa
database
Launching component and product checkers...
Downloading file report-update: 0%
Downloading file report-update: 100% was finished.
Downloading file pool/PSA_18.0.31_4506/examiners/py_launcher.sh: 0%
Downloading file pool/PSA_18.0.31_4506/examiners/py_launcher.sh: 100% was finished.
Error: An error occurred during performing of installation PREP actions (see log for details). Installation was rolled back.
Warning! Not all packages were installed.
Please check if your system services are operable.
Please resolve this issue and try to install the packages again.
Visit https://support.plesk.com/ to search for a solution.
```

Any help would be great.

Log

https://pastebin.com/hyHaxSju

Comment: tesco self service " help is coming "

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
mysql -uadmin -p`cat /etc/psa/.psa.shadow` -e"DROP DATABASE psa;"
```

removing the old database did the trick.

[SOURCE](https://www.ionos.com/help/server-cloud-infrastructure/accordions-to-plesk-panel/troubleshooting/rescue-plesk-after-a-failed-update/)